# Can this SQL with subquery in SELECT be converted to Hibernate 3.0.5 HQL?

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql, outer-join

Is it possible to convert the following into HQL 3.0.5 using any approach? Subqueries, outer joins with predicates, etc?

```
SELECT c.case_id, 
       (SELECT MAX(a.begin_date)
          FROM assignment a
         WHERE a.case_id = c.case_id)  
  FROM case c
```

The relationship between case and assignment is 1 to many. The intent of the query is to return all cases and their most recent assignment begin date, if one exists.

I'm having difficulty finding exactly what Hibernate 3.0.5 supports and what it doesn't but I've seen indications that it only supports subqueries in the WHERE.

EDIT: If no assignment exists for a given case, the case_id should still return and the assignment begin date returned should be null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, your SQL query can be rewritten with `JOIN` and `GROUP BY` instead of subquery:

```
SELECT c.case_id, MAX(a.begin_date)
FROM case c LEFT JOIN assignment a ON a.case_id = c.case_id
GROUP BY c.case_id
```

In this form it can be easily converted to HQL, something like this (depends on mapping):

```
SELECT c.id, MAX(a.beginDate)
FROM Case c LEFT JOIN c.assignments a
GROUP BY c.id
```

Comment: I just added an EDIT to the question. I need the case to always return, even if there are no corresponding assignments. Would you queries work with left outer joins just as well?

Comment: Nevermind. Looks like it should return the cases even if there is no assignment as-is. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

HQL does supports subselects provided the underlaying DB has it[Eg. Oracle 10g].
As explained in this [article](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html).